# Torch - How to calculate average of tensors with the same indexes

Tags: python, matrix, pytorch

Suppose having two matrices: X(m, n) and index matrix I(m, 1). Every item in index matrix `I_k` represents the index of the kth element `X_k` in X.

And suppose the index is in the range of [0, 1, 2, ..., j-1]

I would like to calculate the average of tensors in X with the same index `i` and return a result matrix R(j, n).

For example,

```
X = [[1, 1, 1],
     [2, 2, 2],
     [3, 3, 3]]

I = [0, 0, 1]
```

The result matrix should be:

```
R = [[torch.mean(([1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]))],
     [torch.mean(([3, 3, 3]))]
```

which equals to:

```
R = [[1.5, 1.5, 1.5],
     [3, 3, 3]]
```

My current solution is to traverse through `m`, stack the tensors with the same index and perform `torch.mean`.

Is there a way avoiding traversing through `m`? It seems not elegant and rather time-consuming.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding `I = [0, 0, 1]` and how that equals to getting `R`. Is there a typo?

Comment: @Sean ```X_0``` and ```X_1``` have the same index 0 and  ```R_0``` equals to the average of ```X_0``` and ```X_1```.

Comment: How do `X_0` and `X_1` both have index 0? If I do `X[0]` it'll equal `[1, 1, 1]` and if I do `X[1]` it'll be `[2, 2, 2]`.

Comment: @Sean The index here means ```I[0]``` and ```I[1]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
ret = torch.empty_like(X)
ret.scatter_reduce_(0, I.unsqueeze(-1).expand_as(X), X, "mean", include_self=False)
```

should do what you want.
Now, note that this is a fairly new method so it may not be particularly performant. If you bump into an issue with this method, you may be better off running `scatter_add_` on the tensor X and a tensor of ones and then divide.

If you want to also have a smaller tensor as output, you may want to figure out how many indices and with that infer the size of out.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want. And ```scatter_reduce_``` is supported by pytorch >= 1.11.0, so I will use ```scatter_add_``` instead.